# Sendmail doesn't receive messages from other domains

Tags: networking, email, dns, sendmail

I'm trying to set up sendmail on my server. But so far I encountered one problem: I can't receive messages from public email services. `/var/log/mail.log` shows nothing, like post doesn't reach my server at all.

Local users can send messages to each other with no problem.
Outgoing mail is also works almost fine (being blocked as spam yet, but at least servers are responding)

DNS server records was set to (server IP and domain was replaced):

```
@|MX|post.mydomain.com
post|A|111.222.222.111
```

In sendmail.mc replaced `DAEMON_OPTIONS('Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl` with `DAEMON_OPTIONS('Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp')dnl` according to given comment:

```
dnl # Daemon options - restrict to servicing LOCALHOST ONLY !!!
dnl # Remove `, Addr=' clauses to receive from any interface
```

Searched everywhere and now I'm out of options. Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm almost willing to downvote this because you have anonymized away the *one* piece of information that might actually be relevant. Check that your DNS MX record *actually* points to where it's supposed to. The fact that your server doesn't see any traffic is highly indicative of that other servers can't find yours.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, Sorry for being paranoid, but yet I have no proper security (or just too newbie yet) to show of all the information. But how can I check it? `host -t mx mydomain.com` shows `mydomain.com mail is handled by 10 post.mydomain.com`. Post.mydomain.com record points to the same IP as mydomain.com. Both are accessible from web browser (from Internet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I have thought: "Do I need to set up port forwarding on my router? No, I don't. It's connected directly."

Today I woke up myself with: "No, it's definitely not!"

So requests were simply filtered by my router. I added ports to "Virtual Server" page, and now it's working relatively well.